# RSA Authentication Manager - Unable to resolve principal by login ID and/or alias

Tags: security, active-directory, troubleshooting, rsa

I'm attempting to setup a RSA authentication manager with a Microsoft Active Directory as the identity source.  When I try to login from the Windows login client the login attempt failed and I recieve the message `Unable to resolve principal by login ID and/or alias` in the authentication monitor.

I am under the understanding that this error message is occuring because Authentication Manager cannot resolve the username `CONTOSO\Operator` to the username `Operator`.

Any suggestions how to resolve the problems mapping the active directory users to the Authentication Manager database? Is there a global alias mask like `CONTOSO\*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the RSA Authentication Client, there is an option to "include domain with login". It was checked. It should not have been.